# Consumo de Web Services para probar

Tags: java

Estoy iniciando en la programación del consumo de *Web Services* con *Java*.

¿Hay ejemplos de *Web Services* que funcionen con los que pueda realizar pruebas?

Comment: ya intentaste con algún servicio de echo? ( Y buscar obviamente en google )

Answer (score -2):

Si está familiarizado con cómo funcionan los servicios *REST*, le comparto este proyecto que le puede servir para armar su propio servicio *REST* en minutos y así probar el funcionamiento de su código usando estos *MOCK web services*.

Para iniciar su *MOCK API* usando `json-server`:

1. Instalar el paquete de json-server
   `npm install -g json-server`
2. Crear un archivo `db.json` con datos en estructuras `json`, por ej.:

```
{
  "notas": [
    { "id": 1, "titulo": "json-server", "usuarioId": 1 }
  ],
  "comentarios": [
    { "id": 1, "cuerpo": "algún texto", "notaId": 1 }
  ],
  "usuarios": [{ "username": "wil", "imagenUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fffC/O https://placeholder.com/" }
}]
```

3. Iniciar el servidor de la *api* *mock* desde su terminal:
   `json-server --watch db.json`
4. Ahora puede usar peticiones a la *API Mock* por ejemplo, comenzar a consumir el *Endpoint* de información de un usuarios con `id=1` podría realizar una petición `GET` a `http://localhost:3000/usuarios/1/`

**Referencias:**

- https://github.com/typicode/json-server
- https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-creating-demo-apis-with-json-server

Comment: Java no es JavaScript

Comment: Consumir una API Rest es independiente del lenguaje de programación que quiera usar, puede ser Java, PHP, Python, Javascript, u otras herramientas como cURL Postman entre otros.

Comment: Efectivamente, es independiente del lenguaje, pero el autor de la pregunta especificó concretamente que quiere usar JAVA, y le has ofrecido un backend JS, no aplica.

Comment: Es que el autor necesita consumir un servicio web desde su código en Java. Y no crear/exponer un servicio Web con Java. ¿Es así @Eslacuare?

Comment: @WillyGuevara Según entiendo, el servicio tiene que estar hecho en Java, y esto es Node, pero tampoco dio muchos detalles como para saberlo exactamente.

Comment: Esperamos a ver que dice @caroco